# Angular вывод элементов

Tags: angular

У меня есть работающий код. Я вывожу данные из JSON placeholder. У меня есть вопрос: щас я вывожу все элементы (все 100), но как можно вывести только например 15? Я пробую сделать обычным циклом, но не получается. Прошу помощи. Добра вам)

Файл album.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-albums',
    templateUrl: './albums.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./albums.component.css']
})

export class AlbumsComponent implements OnInit {

    albums : any[];

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
          .subscribe(value => this.albums = value);
    }
}
```

Файл album.component.html

```
<main>
    <h1>All Albums</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let album of albums">
        {{album.id}} -- {{album.title}}
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
  .subscribe(value => this.albums = value.slice(0, 15));
}
```